# WPF Setting a ListBox ItemTemplate from code

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Ok I have a an WPF appilication, in wich i have a `Resource Dictionary` where i create two different styles for the `ListBox Item.Template`( `Style1` , `Style2` ).
And i set my starting style like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="Lister" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Style1}"/>
```

Now i want to let the user change the style of the `ListBoxItem` whenever he wants.
But i dont have a clue how this is going to be done.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}"
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template1}">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeConditionInTheViewModel}" Value="True">
                  Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Template2}"/>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox
```

Comment: Bravo - impressive speed in which you fired up a trigger.

Comment: Explicit settings take priority over triggers, so the default ItemTemplate should be defined in a style setter.

Comment: I managed to make it work but in onother way. I found it very difficult to make the binding. I just couldnt make it work.So i did it in C# code like this : 
Lister.ItemTemplate=(DataTemplate)FindResource("Style2");